# Chart.js separation lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js and have a line chart like this :

[image].

Is it possible to make separation like on the school line? (see red lines on the picture).

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388901/chart-js-x-axis

Comment: You should embed in the image in your question so we don't have to click a link

Comment: @Adam, I'll take a closer look at the code but I'm afraid not. The chart from your link looks not like what I'm looking for.
CodyBugstein, sorry, I can't due to lack of reputation.

Comment: @ℊααnd, no, that lines on my picture are already done. I'm trying to make something like [this](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-htmffxPyDes/UbOYyOyOScI/AAAAAAAAAeg/iX6clDfWFoU/s320/barError2Grab.jpg) on the X axis. I need short grid lines for each of my label on the bottom of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see another solution: there are additional properties of `gridLines` for these purposes.

```
gridLines: {
  display: true,
  drawBorder: true,
  drawOnChartArea: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** It is possible !!

You can achieve that using the following chart plugin :

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      var x_axis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      //loop through ticks array
      x_axis.ticks.forEach(function(tick, index) {
         var x = x_axis.getPixelForTick(index);
         var y = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
         var lineHeight = 8;
         var lineColor = 'black';
         //draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, y);
         ctx.lineTo(x, y + lineHeight);
         ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      });
   }
});
```

<sup>* add this at the beginning of your script</sup>

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ ⧩**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      var x_axis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      //loop through ticks array
      x_axis.ticks.forEach(function(tick, index) {
         var x = x_axis.getPixelForTick(index);
         var y = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
         var lineHeight = 8;
         var lineColor = 'black';
         //draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, y);
         ctx.lineTo(x, y + lineHeight);
         ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      });
   }
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false,
         tension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```